# An efficient set data structure in elisp

Tags: elisp

Does elisp provide a builtin efficient set data structure, similar to [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) in Python and [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) in C++?

Comment: Hash tables can be used for that purpose, in fact that's how sets in Ruby work under the hood.

Comment: @wasamasa Do you mean using hash tables with all values set to nil?

Comment: @xhudev No, with all values set to `t`.  That makes it more convenient to check for set inclusion than with `nil` as value.

Comment: Specify more clearly what properties you want of the data structure. Sets can be implemented in various ways, depending on which of their properties are considered most important in a particular context. There is no single implementation that is best for all uses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way to handle sets in lisps is to use [hash tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html). In fact, this is how sets are implemented in languages which do provide a dedicated interface (like Python). This offers `O(1)` access cost, so is perfect for larger sets.

E.g.:

```
(defun make-set ()
  (make-hash-table))
(defun add-to-set (element set)
  (puthash element t set))
(defun in-set-p (element set)
  (gethash element set nil))
(defun remove-from-set (element set)
  (remhash element set))
```

Set-level operations, like union and intersection, require more work.

PS. When I said "lisps" above I kinda lied. Common Lisp actually offers list-based set-level functions (["Lists as Sets"](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_abb.htm)), but these have access complexity `O(N)` and set-level complexity `O(N^2)`, so they are only suitable for smaller sets.

Answer (score 11):

There are many different ways to implement sets, with very different efficiency profiles.  In Elisp, the two simplest ways to implement sets are probably:

- As a list:  This tends to have poor algorithmic efficiency (such as O(N) complexity to test membership) but works well for small sets.  Adding an element can be as simple as `push` or `cl-pushnew`, and testing is just `memq` or `member`.
- As a hash table:  This has a higher constant cost, but a better algorithmic efficiency, so it works much better for larger sets.  Adding an element is just `(puthash VAL t SET)` and testing membership is just `(gethash VAL SET)`.